# How to output simple wikipedia row data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

I am doing this:

```
<div id="results">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
  jQuery.getJSON("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&list=search&format=json&rvsection=0&srsearch=World_War_II&rvparse", 
  function(data, item) {
      jQuery("#results ul").append("<li>" + item.title + "</li>");
  });
```

That gives me `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` so i tried using `jsonp` but I get the same error.

I would like to retrieve the whole data just as if I clicked on

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=World_War_II&rvsection=0&rvparse

Here it is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wsupf/85/)

Comment: Request from serverside...

Comment: @Jonasw pardon, can you elaborate it more pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to this is to use `&origin=*`

Comment: @CodeBiker typo

Answer (score -2):

Check out the Wikipedia api document. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Comment: this is it: `&origin=*"`

Comment: @rob.m, so others will understand, can you enter &origin=* as the actual answer to this question rather than as a comment?